# Define width and background-color of a div with StencilJS

Tags: css, typescript, stenciljs

I have an array with some properties (values are variable).

```
[{"color": "#2c8646",
  "value": 30
 },
 {"color": "#69c0f9",
  "value": 50 }]
```

And then, I need to return divs with that, something like:

```
render(){
  return (
 <div class="SomeClass" style="width: array[0].value ; background-color: array[0].color" >
)
```

The matter is that style in StencilJS doesn't work like that. I can't use a static css file due that the Array is different any time.

Any idea?

TIA

I need to do something like

```
this.objArray.forEach(element => {

      if(element.color == undefined || element.color == null || element.color == '')
      {
        element.color = this.colors[this.index];
        this.index = this.index == (this.colors.length - 1) ? 0 : (this.index += 1 );
      }

      if(element.value == null  || element.value == 0  )
        element.value = 100;

      if(element.tooltip == null )
        element.tooltip = '';

     return <div class style={`width:${element.value}; background-color ${element.color}`> </div>;

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Stencil allows for styles to be dynamic - a simple example that we can build on would look somethings like this:

```
import { Component, h } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
  shadow: true,
})
export class MyComponent {
  render() {
    return <div style={{ background: "#ffe7e8", border: "2px solid #e66465" }}>Hello, World! I'm Stencil</div>;
  }
}
```

where we just output "Hello World, I'm Stencil!" in a red bordered and pink-ish background.

Note that here, the contents of the `style` attribute has two curly braces - one to denote that we have an object literal:

```json
{ background: "#ffe7e8", border: "2px solid #e66465" }
```

and an outer pair surrounding that object literal to tell Stencil to interpolate/read this value.

We can then add an array of styles, and use the `map()` function in order to show a `div` for each style:

```
import { Component, h } from '@stencil/core';

type Styles = Record<string, string>[];

const myStyles: Styles = [
  { background: "#ffe7e8", border: "2px solid #e66465" },
  { background: "#26b72b", border: "1px dashed blue" }
]

@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
  shadow: true,
})
export class MyComponent {
  render() {
    return (<div>{myStyles.map((myStyle) => <div style={myStyle}>Hello, World! I'm Stencil</div>)}</div>);
  }
}
```

Note that:

1. `Styles` is just an array containing a mapping of strings to strings
2. `myStyles` contains two different styles for us to iterate over
3. We use `map()` in the `render` function - this is necessary in order to have a new `div` returned for each and every entry in `myStyles`.
4. We use only one set of curly braces, as `myStyle` in the `render` function is already an object

Using `map` is important, as `forEach` does not return a new value for each iteration. If I were to change my `render` function to:

```
  render() {
    return (<div>{myStyles.forEach((myStyle) => <div style={myStyle}>Hello, World! I'm Stencil</div>)}</div>);
  }
```

Nothing would render.

To make your `forEach` workable, I'd suggest changing:

1. `forEach` to a `map`
2. updating the style generation logic to build an object literal instead of a string like so:

```
const newStyle = {
  width: element.value,
  background-color: element.color
};
return <div class style={newStyle}> </div>;
```